# Mousewheel not working in some areas of the screen

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

Starting today, my mousewheel stopped working on some areas of the screen. For example, it works absolutely perfectly in the left 20% of the screen. In other (seemingly random) areas, about 50% of mouse-scroll events are handled, the rest ignored. But on most of the screen, no mouse-scroll events register at all.
Sometimes single scroll-down events are even registered as scroll-up.

What blows my mind is, that the behaviour is totally dependant on where the mouse pointer is at the moment.

It doesn't matter if I have any windows open, even after system restart the behaviour is there right on the desktop. I can for example open the audio volume control by clicking on the speaker-icon in the system-tray (bottom right, next to the time and date). As long as that control is open, mouse scroll should adjust volume wherever the cursor is on the screen, but mouse-scroll events behave as described above.

I already tried uninstalling the mouse driver, putting mouse into another USB-port (on-board vs. USB-3 extension card), with no effect.

I also removed all other USB devices and for a moment this seemed to fix it. Everything worked normally for a minute or so, even after putting the other devices back in. Then the problem returned. Now, even removing the other devices does not fix it. The problematic areas on the desktop seem to have shrunk quite a bit however, it's only an area at the top right that does seem to have the issue at the moment.

What ever could cause such an issue?

Comment: Are you using a single monitor? Do you have a second mouse, touchpad, or pointing device connected? Is the new mouse using a customization utility like Logitech Options?

Comment: Yes, it's a single monitor on a desktop PC. No second mouse or pointing devices of any sort. And it's not a new mouse, I've been using it for a year at the very least (and that same model for maybe 5 years). It's a Logitech M500, and there's no Logitech software installed at all, and I can't see any processes that hint to Logitech. There's nothing mouse-related in the system tray as well.

Comment: It sounds like this might be a hardware issue. If you haven't already, try another mouse. Also, if you the Logitech SetPoint utility, you could assign the thumb buttons to vertical scroll to see if it is the wheel itself. Let me know how it shakes out. This is a strange one.

Comment: The problem disappeared completely after a while. Hardware issue seemed unplausible to me as the behaviour was dependant on the current pointer position, which is totally software dependant. I now realize however that I did NOT remove every USB device, I in fact left in a Bluetooth dongle which I simply overlooked, so maybe it was some weird interference through that..!? If the problem should reoccur I'll try that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today the problem reoccurred.

First thing I tried was removing the bluetooth dongle from my front USB slot (overlooked that one last time). No effect.
Then I tried another mouse of the same model. No effect.

Then I realized that not the cursor position is relevant to the problem, but **the position of the mouse on my table**.

Turns out the mouse wheel stops working when bright sunlight shines through the slits and gaps between the mouse wheel and the mouse buttons. The sun only hits the surface of my table at certain positions, and the problem occured when the mouse was in that area. When the mouse was in a bright area and the mouse wheel did not work, I could make it work by simply blocking the sunlight with my hand. And that was true for both of my Logitech M500 mice.

It's true what they say. Software development and sunlight don't go well together.